# Azure Pipelines AzureWebApp@1 Task Start and Stop App Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am deploying my web app via Azure Pipelines to our Azure Webservice with the following YAML script:

```
 - deployment: Api
    displayName: Deploy Web Api
    pool:
       name: 'MyApi-FMMR'
    environment: 'Prod'
    strategy:
     runOnce:
       deploy:
        steps:
        - task: AzureWebApp@1
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: 'AzureHFMG'
            appType: webApp
            appName: 'cp-admin-api-prod'
            package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/*.zip'
```

But I am wondering, weather it is necessary to Stop the WebApp before I use this task to deploy a new version.
In the old classic pipelines I always observed something like this:

[image]

Here two tasks "Stop" and "Start" are added before and after the task, but if I try this out it works even without those.

Is it a best practice to add those tasks? Or are they implicitly called by the "AzureWebApp@1" task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need those tasks; the Deploy task will automatically restart the service.

However, this has downsides:

1. there will be a short amount of downtime
2. some services suffer for being stopped and restarted suddenly, for example not being able to respond until warmed up

These can be mitigated by using a [staging slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) to deploy the code to, before swapping the slots to allow the new deployment to seamlessly take over.